# groupby count in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My data frame looks like -

```
id      age      gender       category
1        34        m             b
1        34        m             c
1        34        m             b
2        28        f             a
2        28        f             b
3        23        f             c
3        23        f             c 
3        23        f             c
```

I want my data frame looks like -

```
id      age      gender       a      b      c
1        34        m          0      2      1
2        28        f          1      1      0
3        23        f          0      0      2
```

I have done -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.groupby(['id','age','gender']).pivot('category').agg(F.count('category')).fillna(0)
df.show()
```

How to manage in pyspark?Is there any correct way through I can manage this thing

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @cronoik - edited my question.can u help me?

Comment: Sorry I still don't get your question. Your code produce already what you are looking for (except that the third row looks like `|  3| 23|     f|  0|  0|  3|`).

Comment: @cronik you are right...3rd row should be changed

Comment: @NikitaAgarwal Your code looks right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks fine to me but when I tried running it, I see this

```py
df = spark.read.csv('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/txt_sample.txt',header=True,inferSchema=True,sep="\t")
df = df.groupby(['id','age','gender']).pivot('category').agg(count('category')).fillna(0)
df.show()

df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [id: integer, age: integer ... 5 more fields]
+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+
| id|age|gender|  a|  b|  c| c |
+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+
|  2| 28|     f|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  1| 34|     m|  0|  2|  1|  0|
|  3| 23|     f|  0|  0|  1|  2|
+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+
```

It is because of an extra space character after c in the last two rows.

just trim the spaces by using rtrim()

```py
df = spark.read.csv('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/txt_sample.txt',header=True,inferSchema=True,sep='\t')
df = df.withColumn('Category',rtrim(df['category'])).drop(df['category'])
df = df.groupby(['id','age','gender']).pivot('Category').agg(count('Category')).fillna(0)
df.show()

df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [id: integer, age: integer ... 4 more fields]
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
| id|age|gender|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
|  2| 28|     f|  1|  1|  0|
|  1| 34|     m|  0|  2|  1|
|  3| 23|     f|  0|  0|  3|
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
```